# How to structure a render function with img.src

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code in my `render()` function and I'm trying to change an images height and width dinamically whenever a state change occurs:

```
render() {

    const imageURL = photos[this.state.currentImage].url;

    const base_image = new Image();
    base_image.src = imageURL;

    var wrh = base_image.width / base_image.height;
    var newWidth = 600;
    var newHeight = newWidth / wrh;

    return (

       <img height={newHeight} width={newWidth}>
    )

}
```

I know that I have to add a `base_image.onload` function to make sure that when `base_image.src` is set the image starts loading but the code jumps to `return()` and renders the image with wrong `height` and `width` values because the image did not finish loading and I did not fetch the correct values. How can I structure my code so the image does not get rendered before the `base_image` has finished loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `state variable` to store the image's ratio. In the `render` method, you can use conditional rendering to prevent displaying the image until the ratio has been computed

```
const width = 600;

class YourComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ratio: undefined,
      currentImage: 0
    };
    this.image = new Image();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.img.onload = () => {
      this.setState({
        ratio: this.img.naturalWidth / this.img.naturalHeight  
      });
    };
    this.img.src = photos[this.state.currentImage].url;
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.state.currentImage !== prevState.currentImage) {
      this.img.src = photos[this.state.currentImage].url;
    }
  }

  render() {
    const {ratio} = this.state;
    return ratio && <img width={width} height={width/ratio}>;
  }
}
```